# Best way to search/index the data - with and without whitespace

Tags: elasticsearch

I am having a problem indexing and searching for words that may or may not contain whitespace...Below is an example

Here is how the mappings are set up:

```
curl -s -XPUT 'localhost:9200/test' -d '{
    "mappings": {
        "properties": {
            "name": {
                "street": {
                    "type": "string",
                    "index_analyzer": "index_ngram",
                    "search_analyzer": "search_ngram"
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "settings": {
        "analysis": {
            "filter": {
                "desc_ngram": {
                    "type": "edgeNGram",
                    "min_gram": 3,
                    "max_gram": 20
                }
            },
            "analyzer": {
                "index_ngram": {
                    "type": "custom",
                    "tokenizer": "keyword",
                    "filter": [ "desc_ngram", "lowercase" ]
                },
                "search_ngram": {
                    "type": "custom",
                    "tokenizer": "keyword",
                    "filter": "lowercase"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}'
```

This is how I built the index:

```
curl -s -XPUT 'localhost:9200/test/name/1' -d '{ "street": "Lakeshore Dr" }'
curl -s -XPUT 'localhost:9200/test/name/2' -d '{ "street": "Sunnyshore Dr" }'
curl -s -XPUT 'localhost:9200/test/name/3' -d '{ "street": "Lake View Dr" }'
curl -s -XPUT 'localhost:9200/test/name/4' -d '{ "street": "Shore Dr" }'
```

Here is an example of the query that is not working correctly:

```
curl -s -XGET 'localhost:9200/test/_search?pretty=true' -d '{

   "query":{
      "bool":{
         "must":[
            {
               "match":{
                  "street":{
                     "query":"lake shore dr",
                     "type":"boolean"
                  }
               }
            }
         ]
      }
   }
}';
```

If a user attempts to search  for "Lake Shore Dr", I want to only match to document 1/"Lakeshore Dr"
If a user attempts to search for "Lakeview Dr", I want to only match to document 3/"Lake View Dr"

So is the issue with how I am setting up the mappings (tokenizer?, edgegram vs ngrams?, size of ngrams?) or the query (I have tried things like setting the minimum_should_match, and the analyzer to use), but I have not been able to get the desired results.

Thanks all.